# Git: Stashed Changes But Still Can't Pull

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu-16.04

I have looked all over and followed several different sets of instructions on this but none seems to work for me.

I have a GitHub repository and I have made some changes on my local machine and some on my Linux server and was hoping to merge the two.

In the past, I have used the `git stash` command and then been able to `pull` and then `pop` the stash to merge. I have never done this on Linux but I assumed it would the same as windows. However, even though I have stashed my changes on the server I am still unable to pull and receive this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
aFolder/aDifferentFolder/aFile.py
```

So naturally I checked to see if my stash had gone through using `git stash show` and I got confirmation that the stash existed because the top line showed this:

```
aFolder/aDifferentFolder/aFile.py                 | 2110 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------------------
```

This is very strange. But decided that I didn't even want my changes on the server that much anyway so I decided to delete them using `git reset --hard` and then tried to pull and was met with the same error!

So in summary a list of things I have tried:
`git stash`
`git reset --hard` 
`git clean -f` 
`git add . && git stash`
`git reset aFolder/aDifferentFolder/aFile.py`

EDIT: Just to add more info here is the message I get upon calling `stash`:

```
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 1d49f3a Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/username/repository
HEAD is now at 1d49f3a Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/username/repository
```

Comment: Have you done `git clean`?

Comment: Try `git add . && git stash`

Comment: I tried `git clean -f` then `git pull` and  `git add .` `git stash` then `git pull` and still got the error. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: On Mac this situation can happen when filenames clash with different cases. In Linux not sure. In any case your question does not have enough details about the git state of the conflicting file.

Answer (score 0):

I never found out why this happened but a solution that worked for me was creating a new branch pushing to that and then merging with the master branch. Afterwards I deleted the useless branch.